# Import Multileaders from AutoCAD into QGIS

Tags: qgis, autocad

I would like to take a set of multileaders and get the locations they point to and the text they contain as a layer or. I can get the locations of where the text sits but I am interested in where it points to as this is about the features at the points not annotation.

Answer (score -1):

QGIS has a plugin named, dxf2shape. There is an option to convert Cad Text to shapefile Points. Each point will be located at the Text origin and contain the Cad Text string in an attribute. Shapefiles cannot store Annotation.

But there is no way to set the point position to the leader's origin.

Comment: I don't want to just see the leaders, I need the point and the text as 1 feature with the text as an attribute so I can do a DB join to pull in more info

Comment: I have edited the answer. good luck.

Comment: Sadly it's not the text origin that is of interest